# Show that there must be at least one real solution...

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Having a bit of trouble in what way I am suppose to go about solving this problem. Any guidance would be great.

Show that there is at least one real solution to:$$x^5 - x^2 - 4 = 0 $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem. A continuous function has limits positive and negative infinity as x approaches positive and negative infinity.

Comment: You don't even have to prove those limits to positive and negative infinity; just take $x=-10$ and $x=10$ and show they're positive and negative respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since at $x  \rightarrow \infty $ function tends to $\infty$ and at $x  \rightarrow -\infty$ function tends to $-\infty$ . Hence it will cut $x$-axis at some point for sure since function is well-continuous.This is true for all polynomials with odd degree.

Comment: What is well-continuous?

Comment: @Olba12 It sounds good.

Comment: Will keep that in mind at my next exam.

Answer (score 3):

If z is a complex root of a polynomial with real coefficients, then also conjugate of z is a root (that is an easy thing to prove). 
Therefore, if a polynomial with real coefficient does not have real roots, it must have an even number of roots.
Now, this polynomial has 5 roots by Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, thus at least one solution must be real.

Answer (score 2):

set $$f(x)=x^5-x^2-4$$ then we have $$f(1)=-4$$ and $$f(2)=2^5-4-4=24>0$$ and the function $$f(x)$$ is continuous, thus there is at least one solution in the interval

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial has degree $5$ so it has $5$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$. We known that the complex roots are always couple of conjugate numbers if the coefficients are real numbers, so, for the given polynomial, we can have $4$ complex roots and  the one other root must be real.